# Counting element by class name not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to count elements with a particular class name, which get added and removed as part of a toggle control. This means that the count reported is incorrect.

I have noticed that my current implementation skips the first selected element (i.e. does not count), and only starts counting on the second.

My code is as follows:

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]">

    Full Colour
    <p>&pound;50 and up to 1 hour</p>

    <button class="button button-custom" ng:click="bookingSelected = !bookingSelected; 
                              $parent.$parent.activeProfileHeader = false;
                              $parent.$parent.displayBookingFooter(true);" ng-class="{ 'button-custom-padding': bookingSelected === true, 
                                'button-positive': bookingSelected === false,
                                'booking-selected' : bookingSelected === true, 
                                'button-balanced': bookingSelected === true}">{{bookingSelected && '✔' || 'Book'}}</button>
  </div>

<br>

  Total: {{numItems('booking-selected')}}

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope, $window) {
  $scope.bookingSelected = false;

  $scope.numItems = function(className) {
    return $window.document.getElementsByClassName(className).length;
  };
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ha5oac6v/

**UPDATE: Sorry appears, the code in the jsfiddle does not work.**

Comment: Your code doesnt' work cause you misspelled ng-click. Check you wrote ng:click. Also, this thing of counting the classes doesn't seem a good idea. Why don't you push the selected items into an array and count the array length instead?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rvukp5Lh/ basically it works, downvoted.

Comment: How would I push the selected items into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of `=== true` and `=== false`.

Instead do:

```
ng-class="{ 
    'button-custom-padding': bookingSelected, 
    'button-positive': !bookingSelected,
    'booking-selected' : bookingSelected, 
    'button-balanced': bookingSelected
}"
```